# how to query latest row in relational table after joining needed data

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

i've done some digging around the past couple days on this site and elsewhere and i can't seem to find an answer to a specific query i want to run

i have 4 tables: Posts, PrivateMessagePosts, Users, and Offenses. Offenses are tied to either a `Post.id` or `PrivateMessagePost.id` but not a user. they look like this:

`Offense`

| id | post_id | private_message_post_id | end_time | is_ban |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | null | $some_datetime | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 34 | null | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |

`Post`

| id | author_id | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | hello |
| 2 | 54 | world |

`PrivateMessagePost`

| id | author_id | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | hello |
| 2 | 23 | world |

`User`

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | joe |
| 2 | bill |

so far I have a SQLAlchemy query which will get a list of posts given a thread ID (that part is irrelevant), and return them with all of the offenses tied to them. it looks like this:

```py
 db.session.query(
      Post,
      Thread.title,
      User.username,
      User.byline,
      User.avatar_url,
      User.registered_on,
      User.id
      Forum.id,
      Forum.title,
      func.group_concat(offense.id),
      func.group_concat(offense.is_ban),
      func.group_concat(func.coalesce(offense.end_time, "None")),
      func.group_concat(offense.post_id),
      active_offense_one.id,
  )
  .join(Thread, base_post.thread_id == Thread.id)
  .join(Forum, Forum.id == Thread.forum_id)
  .join(some_user, some_user.id == base_post.author_id)
  """
  this join gets the list of offenses that are tied to
  the specific post we're querying,

  but irrelevant to the question
  """
  .join(
      offense,
      and_(
          offense.post_id == base_post.id,
          offense.approved_user_id > 0,
          or_(offense.end_time > current_time, offense.is_ban == True),
      ),
      isouter=True,
  )
  .group_by(
      base_post.id,
      active_offense_one.id
  )
```

which translates to this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  posts_1.id AS posts_1_id, 
  posts_1.body AS posts_1_body, 
  posts_1.posted_at AS posts_1_posted_at, 
  posts_1.updated_at AS posts_1_updated_at, 
  posts_1.ip_address AS posts_1_ip_address, 
  posts_1.thread_id AS posts_1_thread_id, 
  posts_1.author_id AS posts_1_author_id, 
  threads.title AS threads_title, 
  users_1.username AS users_1_username, 
  users_1.byline AS users_1_byline, 
  users_1.avatar_url AS users_1_avatar_url, 
  users_1.registered_on AS users_1_registered_on, 
  forums.id AS forums_id, 
  forums.title AS forums_title, 
  """
  using group_concat to get a CSV of all the offenses tied to this specific post
  """
  group_concat(offenses_1.id) AS group_concat_1, 
  group_concat(offenses_1.is_ban) AS group_concat_2, 
  group_concat(coalesce(offenses_1.end_time, %(coalesce_1)s)) AS group_concat_3, 
  group_concat(offenses_1.post_id) AS group_concat_4, 
  offenses_2.id AS offenses_2_id, users_1.id AS users_1_id
FROM offenses AS offenses_2, posts AS posts_1 
INNER JOIN threads ON posts_1.thread_id = threads.id 
INNER JOIN forums ON forums.id = threads.forum_id 
INNER JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.id = posts_1.author_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN offenses AS offenses_1 
  ON offenses_1.post_id = posts_1.id 
  AND offenses_1.approved_user_id > %(approved_user_id_1)s 
  AND (offenses_1.end_time > %(end_time_1)s OR offenses_1.is_ban = true) 
GROUP BY posts_1.id, offenses_2.id
```

That's all great and working fine, BUT now i need a way to say "give me the latest offense that this user has that is either not past it's end time or is a ban. it doesn't matter if the offense isn't tied to the post - it just needs to be tied to the user"

Comment: change the order and use limit

Comment: @cards can you show me an example? the current join on offenses is getting all offenses for a post, which is unrelated. what i need additionally is the first offense that the user has ordered by is_ban.asc() and end_time.desc().

the offense i'm trying to access isn't necessarily on the post we're selecting but any post or PM the user has made